# C# Parsing/Saving XML Documents

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, arrays, xml-parsing

My tasks seems to sound simple but is proving very difficult. I have a XML file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ref:ReferralDocument xmlns:ref="http://ref.com" xmlns:gen="http://ref.com"
                      xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:pbr="ref.com" 
                      xmlns:xsi="ref.com" schemaVersion="2.9">
 <ref:MessageDetails>
  <gen:TestID>
   <gen:IdValue>2412665651</gen:IdValue>
   <gen:IdScheme>Test</gen:IdScheme>
   <gen:IdType>Person</gen:IdType>
  </gen:TestID>
 </ref:MessageDetails>
 <gen:Name>
  <gen:StructuredName>
   <gen:GivenName>Test</gen:GivenName>
   <gen:FamilyName>Test</gen:FamilyName>
  </gen:StructuredName>
  <gen:NameType>Current Name</gen:NameType>
 </gen:Name>
</ref:MessageDataRef>
```

I want to read every XML element in to a XML Element object. As store them in a List or Array of XML Elements.

```
//Create new document
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("C:\\Users\\liam.mccann\\Documents\\test.xml");
```

After loading in in I haven't had any success in getting every element only seem to be able to get the first.

So simple  Load XML Document >> Validate XML >> Get Scheme Version from first Element >> Parse To XML Element List.

After parsing i hope it would be easy to restructure the document and save it again. And the document been the same.

Hopefully someone is able to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to read every XML element in to a XML Element object. As store
>   them in a List or Array of XML Elements.

You could do the following:

```
var array = document.SelectNodes("/descendant-or-self::*")
                    .OfType<XmlElement>()
                    .ToArray();
```

Having said that, if all you're intending is:

> After parsing i hope it would be easy to restructure the document and
>   save it again.

then storing the elements in an array is probably not the optimal approach. You can use the `XmlDocument` class itself (or better yet - the new LINQ approach: `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`).

Here's the MSDN document that hopefully can get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387084%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: I get a "Possible null assignment to entity marked with not null attribute" on the select nodes line

Comment: Which means you're using Resharper: more kudos to you Sir. As noted above the answer is just showing that this is possible, though I still don't believe this is the best approach. Here's a code that would avoid getting the warning if you're interested in pursuing it:

`var xmlNodeList = document.SelectNodes("/descendant-or-self::*");
            if (xmlNodeList != null)
            {
                var array = xmlNodeList.OfType<XmlElement>().ToArray();
            }`

Comment: + 1 great answer, only thing is! After reading it from the file like u suggested to XML Element Array.

Is it possible to save it with the parent child structure still in place?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'in place'. Those XmlElements in that array are simply references to the elements of the original document; changing them modifies that document. If you want to preserve a copy of the original, you can save yourself a copy using `document.Clone()`.